# Where should js.erb file reside

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an ajax enabled view in my Organizations controller which has a list of related members. When I click on the view member profile link I would like the members/member partial to render the selected members details in an Aside element.

Assuming everything is working, should the show.js.erb file reside in the members or organizations view folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be in the members view folder.

Then you'd access it in your view like so:

```
<% @organization.members.each do |member| %>
  <%= link_to member.name, member, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```